# gridview control color

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an editable gridview. I was able to change the color of the column heads but I couldn't figure it how to change the control links (edit,update,cancel) color?
It's blue in default and that doesn't look good in a black background.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GridView1_RowDataBound`](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/17/10085776/how-to-use-gridview1rowdatabound-event.aspx) method for this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
...
</asp:GridView>
```

---

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // searching through the rows
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        bool isnew = (bool)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IsNew");
        if ( isnew ) e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#FAF7DA"); // is a "new" row
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I was asking for. The method above will change the row's background color.